# How to arrange items in QGridLayout when resizing?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgridlayout

I have a QGridLayout where I add several widgets dynamically, using [QGridLayout::addWidget()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#addWidget). I have no problem for these widgets, as they are all the same.

However, I'd like to know how to handle their alignment when I'll resize the widget containing the grid layout. For example, if my widget is wide enough, I could fit 5 widgets on a single row:

```
------------------------------------------------
| -------  -------  -------  -------  -------  |
| |  1  |  |  2  |  |  3  |  |  4  |  |  5  |  |
| -------  -------  -------  -------  -------  |
|                                              |
```

But if I reduce the width of the widget, I'd like to have all the widgets visible, that means creating new row(s):

```
--------------------
| -------  ------- | 
| |  1  |  |  2  | | 
| -------  ------- | 
| -------  ------- | 
| |  3  |  |  4  | |
| -------  ------- | 
| -------          |
| |  5  |          |
| -------          |
|                  |
```

I think it can be done via the resize event, but how?

Comment: QGridLayout does not implement that policy, if you want to create this behavior you must create your own layout, the following link shows how to do it: [How to Write A Custom Layout Manager](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html#how-to-write-a-custom-layout-manager), Also give an example of a layout like the one you want: [Flow Layout Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html)

Comment: @eyllanesc Ah, neat. Is there a reason why it's not doable with QGridLayout? If you want to lay your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I already posted an answer

Comment: @eyllanesc Not at the time I commented ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Layouts are used to manage the layout and sizes of a set of widgets. QGridLayout is oriented to handle the widgets inside a static grid, that is to say that the position in column and row of an item does not change reason why it is not possible to create that type of disposition.

Qt has a great documentation, so it also tells us how to create custom layouts: [How to Write A Custom Layout Manager](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html#how-to-write-a-custom-layout-manager)

The above link shows an example that is precisely what you want: [Flow Layout Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html)